# Forced Non-blocking refresh of Cache

Tags: java, caching, guava, ehcache

I want a cache refresh policy where if cache values become stale after 5 minutes, I need to trigger refresh for the value at say 4th minute so that the new value is available at 5th minute and any request that tries to fetch data at 5th minute neither has to wait for the load nor gets stale data.

With Guava if I use refreshAfterWrite(4, Minute) and expireAfterWrite(5, Minute) together I can solve this problem for keys that are frequently queried. However I have few keys that are very rarely queried and for them the request might have to wait for load.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: A cache holds transient, recomputable data that is often much smaller than the full data set. So removing infrequently used entries is ideal. If you want the full data set, you might have a scheduled thread reload and swap a map.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing exists as a feature in Ehcache 2.x under the name [*scheduled refresh ahead*](http://terracotta.org/documentation/4.1/bigmemorymax/api/refresh-ahead#scheduled-refresh-ahead) which uses the quartz scheduler.

This feature allows you to schedule a refresh of (a part of) the key set present in the cache at regular intervals. Note that in the case you refresh the whole key set, it can be quite a load on your system based on the key set size and the time it takes to refresh all entries.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation explains](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#when-does-cleanup-happen) that the cache doesn't do any work in the background for you (and that this is actually a feature). So if your cache is not high-throughput enough to ensure all desired keys are always recent, you should create a task (e.g. using `ScheduledExecutorService`) which occasionally refreshes all your keys.

This might look like:

```
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(
    () -> cache.asMap().keys().stream().forEach(cache::refresh), 4, 4, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```